# Basic math calculation issue with Arduino

Tags: math, arduino, arduino-uno

I am doing a basic operation in Arduino and for some reason (this is why I need you) it gives me a totally inappropriate result. Below is the code:

```
long init_H_top; //I am declaring it a long to make sure I got enough bytes
init_H_top=251*255/360; //gives me -4 and it should be 178
```

Any idea why it does that?
I am very confused... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *variable* may be a `long` but your *constants* (`251`, `255`, and `360`) are not.

They are `int` types so will calculate giving an `int` result which will then be put into the `long` variable, *after* any overflow has already done the damage.

Since Arduino has a 16-bit `int` type, `251 * 255` (`64005`) will exceed the maximum integer of `32767` and result in behaviour like you're seeing. The value `64005` is `-1531` in 16-bit two's complement and, when you divide that by `360`, you get about `-4.25` which truncates to `-4`.

You should be using `long` constants to avoid this:

```
init_H_top = 251L * 255L / 360L;
```

Comment: great answer! I was expecting something along those lines - that was troubling for me! :)